# debug javascript in .hta file

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-2015, hta

How can I make the debug of the script in the HTML application?
I added a `debugger` into the script. Start application via the console

```
mshta.exe "path\to\my\.hta"
```

Opens a window "visual studio just-in-time debugger". I choose open project in VS. But after the debug is not working. How to fix it. Or are there other ways to debug .hta?

Comment: Some tips: http://maikkoster.com/debugging-vbscript-and-jscript-in-vbs-js-wsf-and-hta-files/ , should work with JS too. And a newer-one: http://maikkoster.com/finally-debugging-vbscript-and-javascript-for-free-visual-studio-community-2013-published/

Comment: @Teemu, I do as written, but the work doesn't stop at breakpoints.

Comment: A bit late but when you attach, make sure you select script instead of native.

Answer (score 1):

I think the best developer tools are in chrome and they continue to improve all of the time.
So you could rename the hta to html, deploy it and run + debug it via chrome (unless you are using features that are not supported outside IE like vbscript/activex/other bad stuff).
I know its a bit of a pain in the start, but personally I think you should build your app in a modular way, from js/css (or sass/less)/html files like any web project, debug it like any web project and in your build generate the 1 big HTA file.

Comment: chrome dev tools don't help, because it uses activex.

Comment: ok, so do what I wrote but just run it in IE (not mshta.exe) instead. It has decent dev tools as well.

Comment: I run it via the console because I need to pass arguments. `mshta.exe "path\to\my\.hta" arg1 arg2 arg3`

Comment: you can mock that easily but you are going places you shouldn't go. activex is not even supported on edge and it is going away. htas in general are not that recommended anymore. personally I would use for a desktop app electron + the embedded nodejs. but i really have no idea what your project is and what dependencies you have. good luck.